# "Image could not be read." in MigraDocCore on Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using Xam.Plugin.Media to capture a photo from the camera and I want to use the stream from the image to print it on a pdf. I tried so many ways to do this but no one is working and always is printed a gray rectangle with the "Image could not be read" on the center. Anyone have an ideia how to fix this ?

here is my code

```
            var paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
            paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
            var iimage = DependencyService.Get<IImage>();
            
            using (Stream stream = MyImage.GetStream())
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl = iimage.Implementation;
                var foto = MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.FromStream($"MyImage_{Id}.jpg", () => stream, 100)
                var image = paragraph.AddImage(foto);
                image.LockAspectRatio = false;
                image.Width = "15cm";
                image.Height = "10cm";
            }
```

Thanks for Helping.

edit 1: I removed the dependen service and Im using MediaPicker instead of Plugin Media and is throwing a NullReferenceException when the ImageSource is created.

Here is the code:

```
            var paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
            paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
            using (Stream stream = await MyImage.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                stream.Position = 0;
                var foto = MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.FromStream($"{MyImageId}.jpg", () => stream, 100);
                var image = paragraph.AddImage(foto);
                image.LockAspectRatio = false;
                image.Width = "15cm";
                image.Height = "10cm";
            }
```

here is the stack trace:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.FromStream (System.String name, System.Func`1[TResult] imageStream, System.Nullable`1[T] quality) [0x00005] in <491d7d6ccaa64ee5ad963f480330f219>:0
at Myproject.MyClass.MyMethod()
'''

Comment: MediaPicker can return a stream, why are using a DependencyService to do this?

Comment: Just an implementation from this example https://github.com/icebeam7/PDFDemo

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android#general-usage

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake i'm not using Media Picker , i'm using plugin media from James Montemagno

Comment: that plugin is no longer maintained, you should switch to MediaPicker

Comment: I removed the Dependency Service and the Plugin Media and added the Media Picker, now is throwing a NullRefernceException  when I create the ImageSource from MigraDoc

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the current code and specific details about the exception you are getting

Comment: You really should be checking to see if the stream you are opening is not null before you start trying to read from it. It would be null if you simply cancelled out of the media picker for example, and then the code you posted above will just fall over.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on line `MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.FromStream...`.  In VS, examine the parts of that long path. Which one is null?

Comment: 1) The code shown doesn't make sense to me. There are two different streams. `stream = await MyImage.OpenReadAsync()` is one. `MigraDocCore...FromStream(...)` is another. Please explain what you want to do with EACH of those TWO streams. 2) Also, which file(s) of that PDFDemo is this code snippet adapted from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ImageSource Implementation is null by default, so I added this code to set the
ImageSource.Impl, before create the Image Source:

```
if(MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl == null)
{
   MigraDocCore.DocumentObjectModel.MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.ImageSource.ImageSourceImpl = new ImageSharpImageSource<Rgba32>();
}
```